# creating an array basedon dataframe values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

If i have an id that has a start date = 1988 and end date as = 2018 and value = 21100 and i want to create a array or dataframe of the dates from 1988 - 2018 i.e (1988,1989,1990...2018) with each date = to the same value of 21100
So i basically want something that looks like:

```
date, id1, id2
1988, 21100,0
1989, 21100,0
1990,21000 ,0
...
1994,21100,4598
...
2013,21100,4598
...
2018,21100,0
```

how could i do this? I want the array to start populating the value based on the start date and to end populating based on the end date. i have multiple id's (268) and i want them to loop through each adding a new column (id2, id3 ... id268). So for example id2 starts at 1994 to 2013 with a value of 4598.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
example = pd.DataFrame({
'id': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
'start date': ['1988', '1988', '2000', '2005'],
'end date': ['2018', '2013', '2005', '2017'],
'value': [2100, 4568, 7896, 68909]
}) 
print (example)
    id start date end date  value
0  id1       1988     2018   2100
1  id2       1988     2013   4568
2  id3       2000     2005   7896
3  id4       2005     2017  68909
```

You can create `Series` in list comprehension and join them together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), replace missing values, convert to integers and last convert index to column `Date` :

```
L = [pd.Series(v, index=range(int(s), int(e)+1)) for s,e,v in 
     zip(example['start date'], example['end date'], example['value'])]
df1 = (pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=example['id'])
         .fillna(0)
         .astype(int)
         .rename_axis('date')
         .reset_index())
```

---

```
print (df1)
id  date   id1   id2   id3    id4
0   1988  2100  4568     0      0
1   1989  2100  4568     0      0
2   1990  2100  4568     0      0
3   1991  2100  4568     0      0
4   1992  2100  4568     0      0
5   1993  2100  4568     0      0
6   1994  2100  4568     0      0
7   1995  2100  4568     0      0
8   1996  2100  4568     0      0
9   1997  2100  4568     0      0
10  1998  2100  4568     0      0
11  1999  2100  4568     0      0
12  2000  2100  4568  7896      0
13  2001  2100  4568  7896      0
14  2002  2100  4568  7896      0
15  2003  2100  4568  7896      0
16  2004  2100  4568  7896      0
17  2005  2100  4568  7896  68909
18  2006  2100  4568     0  68909
19  2007  2100  4568     0  68909
20  2008  2100  4568     0  68909
21  2009  2100  4568     0  68909
22  2010  2100  4568     0  68909
23  2011  2100  4568     0  68909
24  2012  2100  4568     0  68909
25  2013  2100  4568     0  68909
26  2014  2100     0     0  68909
27  2015  2100     0     0  68909
28  2016  2100     0     0  68909
29  2017  2100     0     0  68909
30  2018  2100     0     0      0
```

---

Use `DataFrame` constructor with `range`:

```
start = 1988
end = 2019
val = 21100
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':range(start, end),
                   'id1': val})
```

---

```
print (df)
    date    id1
0   1988  21100
1   1989  21100
2   1990  21100
3   1991  21100
4   1992  21100
5   1993  21100
6   1994  21100
7   1995  21100
8   1996  21100
9   1997  21100
10  1998  21100
11  1999  21100
12  2000  21100
13  2001  21100
14  2002  21100
15  2003  21100
16  2004  21100
17  2005  21100
18  2006  21100
19  2007  21100
20  2008  21100
21  2009  21100
22  2010  21100
23  2011  21100
24  2012  21100
25  2013  21100
26  2014  21100
27  2015  21100
28  2016  21100
29  2017  21100
30  2018  21100
```

Comment: instead of using 1988 and 2018 is there a way i can link it to the start date and end date of the variables. because i have multiple id's (268) and i want them to loop through each adding a new column (id2, id3 ... id268). So for example id2 starts at 1994 to 2013 with a value of 4598.

Comment: @Tamarie - input data are in list? in dictionary? because `i have multiple id's (268) and i want them to loop through each adding a new column (id2, id3 ... id268)....`

Comment: i edited the question. hopefully it makes more sense. Input data is in a dataframe

Comment: @Tamarie - So input dataframe is `df = pd.DataFrame({'start':[1988, 1994],
                   'end':[2018,2013],
                    'val':[21000, 4598]})` for output DataFrame in question?

Comment: i have multiple rows/identifiers, those are just two i gave an example of. If i follow that will have to manually enter in the values for each identifier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208170/discussion-between-jezrael-and-tamarie).